# "Shape" of solutions of 2nd order homogeneous ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Consider a second order homogeneous ODE:
$$P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0.$$
If $P,Q,R$ are constant functions,
then we know that the general solution has the form
$$y=c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2e^{r_2x},$$
$$y=c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2xe^{r_2x},$$
or
$$y=e^{\alpha x}[c_1\cos(\beta x)+c_2\sin(\beta x)],$$
depending on the constants $P,Q,R$.

---

If $P,Q,R$ are not constant, the solutions are not so simple. However, most resources I could find (such as [this one](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Concepts%20and%20Contexts/upfiles/3c3-2ndOrderLinearEqns_Stu.pdf)) do not discuss this case at all. What I was wondering is, even if we can't solve the equation directly, **is it possible to get some meaningful information on the behaviour of the solutions?**
For example, is it possible to tell that the solution "behaves like an exponential" asymptotically, or oscillates like a sine/cosine function? Any reference discussing such questions would be welcome.

Comment: please check your typesetting.

Comment: Are you looking for the theory of [linear dynamical systems?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_dynamical_system)

Comment: @MrYouMath Strangely enough I didn't see the weird symbols in the Safari browser. Sorry about this, it should be fixed now.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for the pointer, I'll look into it.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a nice universal answer here. If you allow for arbitrary $P,Q,R$ then this allows for singular points, regular and otherwise, and the general behavior allowed has many facets. You get series of algebraic functions, logs of trig functions, Bessel functions and a host of other functions that need not (or simply are not) named.

Comment: @RaisinBread A good place to start is "Differential Dynamical Systems" by J. D. Meiss.

Comment: Up until today there is no general solution to this linear 2nd order ODE with non-constant coefficients.  You can use perturbation theory to find approximate or asymptotic solutions.

Comment: well the solutions form a vector space of dimension $2$, so as soon as you know two independant solutions, you know all of them (there is a slight generalisation of this that works with odes of a bit more general form). Also, as long as $P(x)$ doesn't vanish, the solutions cannot blow up in finite time.

Comment: and conversely given two arbitrary functions, unless you are unlucky somewhere, they should both obey a common 2nd order equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function. Observe
$$ \text{det} \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} y & y' & y'' \\ f(x) & f'(x) & f''(x) \\ 
e^x & e^x & e^x \end{array} \right] =0$$
is a 2nd order linear ODE with horrible coefficients which takes $y=f(x)$ as a solution (and $y=e^x$ as a second solution). But, $f(x)$ is nearly arbitrary, so your questions is really a question about characterizing essentially arbitrary functions in terms of exponentials etc.

Comment: Of course, you can replace $e^x$ with a different function and its derivatives if you like, the identity stems from the fact that a repeated row in a determinant produces a result of zero.