# Reference request: Dynamics of a second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Lets say I have a second order, linear and homogeneous ODE of the form
$$
y''(t)=f(t)y'(t)+g(t)y(t).
$$
This kind of ODE is rather easy to solve in some specific cases. But lets assume that the functions $f, g$ depend on some unkown data (such as some unkown constants or even other unkown functions), but we still have some knowledge about the asymptotic behaviour of this functions (for example, positivity for large time or some relation like $f(t)>g(t)$ for $t$ large enough).

I was wondering if you know some book, notes or theory dealing with this type of problem. I found this post: ["Shape" of solutions of 2nd order homogeneous ODEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798120/shape-of-solutions-of-2nd-order-homogeneous-odes) , asking a somehow similar question, but with non-satisfying answers.

Comment: Presumably you mean something like $y''+f y' +g y=0$? There is no general solution. Under some mild conditions on the regularity of $f$ and $g$ it is possible to construct a power series solution for $y$, see [Frobenius' method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method). Approximate solutions can be found using WKB methods

Comment: Yes, the errata is corrected now. I mean, I know there is no general solution, I am not looking for a solution to the equation, just for a general behavior of the dynamics. For example: if $f,g$ are positive for time large enough, it is easy to check that any non trivial solution is always positive (or always negative) for time large enough.

Comment: To find the behavior of $y(t)$ as $t\to t_0$ (if $t_0=\infty$ then make the transformation $s=1/t$), first [classify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point) the point $t_0$ as: ordinary, regular singular, or irregular singular. In the first two cases, you can construct a power series solution to $y$ as $t\to t_0$. For irregular singular points, make the substitution $y(t)=e^{S(t)}$ and then apply the method of [dominant balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_dominant_balance). All this and more is in the book Bender and Orszag: *Advanced mathematical methods*